# Web Application Deployment issue with x64 assemblies

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I have a web application deployment project setup for an ASP.NET application with Visual Studio 2008.  I'm compiling on an x64 system, and the ASP.NET application includes several Managed C++ assemblies that are compiled for x64.

When the deployment project is compiled, the following error occurs:

ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'ClearCanvas.Dicom.Codec.Jpeg, Version=1.0.3827.17909, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
 or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

If I exclude the x64 assemblies from the build, everything runs fine.  Is it possible to use a web deployment project with assemblies compiled for x64?

Note that I also noticed a potential reference to this issue on [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx) page.  The suggested fix on the page does not resolve the issue and doesn't seem related.

Comment: Are you using a x64 App Pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being caused by building the software via msbuild from a standard Visual Studio Command prompt instead of the x64 Win64 Command Prompt.  Once I switched to this alternate build environment, the compile got past this specific error.

I also had subsequent errors with a native DLL not being loaded by the Web Deployment project.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344608/unmanaged-dlls-fail-to-load-on-asp-net-server) question also helped me determine the DLL that was causing the issues, and how to solve the issue (placing the native DLL in the Path).