# IIS can't load dependent DLL

Tags: iis, dll, environment-variables

I have created a DLL with C++/CLI in order to wrap some unmanaged C++ code (e.g. boost). This work quite fine as long as I

- put all dependent DLLs into one folder and
- propagate via `%PATH%` environment that folder to the IIS (requires a restart of the system).

However Microsoft states that it should be enough to put all dependencies within the `bin` directory under the application path. This ends up with saying the following:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'NETLibd.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NETLibd.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NETLibd.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'NETLibd.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +618
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +209
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +94
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +332
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'NETLibd.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090988
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

I have looked at suggestion from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx) and [others](http://bartwullems.blogspot.de/2012/05/aspnet-load-dlls-from-another-location.html) and adjusted the `web.config` accordingly. Neither of them worked out for me.

```
   <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="/bin;bin/modules;/modules;\modules;bin\modules" />
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="boost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_52" publicKeyToken="0" culture="neutral" />
                <codeBase version="0.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/app/bin/modules/boost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
```

Is there any possibility to tell the IIS a specific path just for this application, e.g. via `web.config`. I think on production systems it would not be very wise to make all these libraries via `%PATH%` systemwide available. At least it would be interesting which DLL could not be found (I know about dependency walker, but due to the fact that all DLLs are in the same directory it does not complain about any missing file).

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" is the relevant part of the error message.  With very high odds that it is the Boost dll it cannot find.  It needs to be located by the normal Windows search rules for unmanaged dlls so the .config entries don't apply.  I think the common practice is to copy them into the `system32\inetsrv` directory.  The PATH environment variable will certainly work but doesn't score any points.  Not a huge problem on a web server, you can control it well enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unmanaged DLLs fail to load on ASP.NET server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344608/unmanaged-dlls-fail-to-load-on-asp-net-server)

Comment: Did you resolved it somehow?

Comment: No. I used the first mentioned approach: putting the dependencies in one directory and propagated that via ```%PATH%```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to execute function from C++ DLL which resides in subfolder of 'bin', and on IIS i had to add my web application to AppPool with ADMIN rights. After that, it loads without errors, in common AppPool it won't load (execute) properly.