# Correctly deploying unmanaged binaries in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dllimport

I'm having trouble deploying unmanaged dll's with IIS.

I've read [Embedding unmanaged dll into a managed C# dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666799/embedding-unmanaged-dll-into-a-managed-c-sharp-dll/768429#768429) but I do not want to embed my binaries as I need the system to be extensible.

**Edit to clarify extensibility** To reduce complexity of building plugins to my library I want people to be able to drop binaries including unmanaged ones onto the bin folder and have it centrally managed.

I've also read [Unmanaged DLLs fail to load on ASP.NET server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344608/unmanaged-dlls-fail-to-load-on-asp-net-server) but I cannot manually copy the files to PATH visible folders.

Using the code below I attempted to shadowcopy the unmanaged binaries to the executing folder to then P/Invoke the `LoadLibrary` method to load them into memory.

This throws the following error when it hits `File.Copy`.

`Access to the path 'MyPath\bin\x86' is denied.`

Is there a surefast method to do this? I'm struggling to find any coherent information. I cannot manually change IIS permissions as this is part of a library that could be installed anywhere.

I also cannot use

```
<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
```

**My Code**

```cs
private void RegisterNativeBinaries()
{
    if (NativeBinaries.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    string folder = Is64Bit ? "x64" : "x86";
    string sourcePath = 
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/" + folder);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string targetBasePath = new Uri(assembly.Location).LocalPath;

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
    if (directoryInfo.Exists)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo
                                               .EnumerateFiles("*.dll"))
        {
            if (fileInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant()
                             .StartsWith("IMAGEPROCESSOR"))
            {
                IntPtr pointer;
                string targetPath = Path.GetFullPath(
      Path.Combine(targetBasePath, "..\\" + folder + "\\" + fileInfo.Name));

                // This is where the error is thrown.
                File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath, true);

                try
                {
                    // Load the binary into memory.
                    pointer = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(sourcePath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
                }

                if (pointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(
                        "Cannot load " + fileInfo.Name);
                    }

                    // Store the pointer for freeing later.
                    NativeBinaries.Add(pointer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but I do not want to embed my binaries as I need the system to be extensible." - can you expand on this and explain why?

Comment: I've edited the question slightly to expand on my reasoning. Hopefully that is clear enough.