# Can't find unmanaged library on ASP.NET server

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on my .net web application that need to execute some methods from unmanaged library. I used amazon web services for deploy.
I found the path, where my application placed after deploy:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

It has bin folder with my unmanaged dll:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\Assimp32.dll

To allow my application use unmanaged dll's, I added this folder to environmental variable PATH.
Here is my PATH variable:

> "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin"

I set this variable every time in my "global.asax.cs":

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"));
        }
```

But I got not found error: "The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I made all steps, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344608/unmanaged-dlls-fail-to-load-on-asp-net-server)

Any ideas to fix it? :(

Comment: How are you calling the code in the library? You need to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: I have c# wrapper, provided by other developer.

Comment: You probably need to move C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\Assimp32.dll to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourWebSiteDirectory\bin\Assimp32.dll . You might be able to solve your problem by moving the \bin directory to your websites root directory.

Comment: Not sure. Because in this folder I have all my site. So, I guess it's the root folder for my app..