# Input string was not in a correct format - MediaInfoLib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video, media, media-library, mediainfo

```
    var mi = new MediaInfoLib.MediaInfo();
    mi.Open(Server.MapPath(Model.TimeLineListArray[j].TimeLineMedia));
    int width = int.Parse(mi.Get(MediaInfoLib.StreamKind.Video, 0, "Width"));
```

This code returns error in server, but in local system it is working.

'mi.open' function returns zero in server and in local system returns one.

'mi.Get' function returns "Unable to load MediaInfo library" in server and in local system returns width.

Please help. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: The issue is more general (not linked to MediaInfoLib) about security on ASP servers. Check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344608/unmanaged-dlls-fail-to-load-on-asp-net-server for some hints about loading an unmanaged DLL on an ASP.net server.

Comment: Everything tried.. not working..still in server shows  "Unable to load MediaInfo library"  :(

Answer (score 0):

Check MediaInfoLib's  dll is in bin folder?
And check your all dlls for property copy local is  true?

Comment: Yes the MediaInfo.dll file is there in Bin folder.

Comment: all dlls  property copy local is true?